# List Average for Ints

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and Stackoverflow and I'm trying to teach myself Haskell programming and I'm doing a series of exercises from a book I downloaded and was wondering if you guys could help me out here.

I'm trying to write a function called avgPub which returns the average of all the years of publication for a series of books. The function arguments are: avgPub :: [(String, String, Int)] -> Int. An example of input/output is,

```
> avgPub [("publisher", "book", 1920), ("publisher1", "book1", 1989), ("publisher2", "book2", 1920)]
1943
```

Yesterday, I learned about div, sum, and map, but I'm not sure how to tie it all together for this problem (as the exercise is hinting at). I think that to find the average of a list of Ints, you do `list (x:xs) = (sum (x:xs))`div`length`, but we are dealing with more than just Ints so this won't work.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to tie it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `year' :: [(String, String, Int)] -> Int`. You want to somehow extract the year field from all the records to be able to average them.

The easiest way to do this is to write a function that takes a *single* record and extracts the year. I.e. like this:

```
year :: (String, String, Int) -> Int
year (_, _, i) = i
```

(note that the first argument is not a list)

Then you can make another function, `years`, to get a list of `Int`s from a list of records:

```
years :: [(String, String, Int)] -> [Int]
years xs = map year xs
```

Then all you need to do is to put this together with code for calculating the average of a list of `Int`s:

```
average :: [Int] -> Int
average xs = (sum xs) `div` (length xs)
```

To tie it together:

```
avgPub books = average (years books)
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused on where you're getting "books" from and what the year function is supposed to look like. I'm still pretty lost. Also, the avgPub is not supposed to take in one argument of a string so "avgPub books = average (years books)" doesn't quite make sense (avgPub :: [(String, String, Int)] -> Int).

Comment: `books` is just the name of the first argument to `avgPub`. It doesn't have to represent a string, it can be a `[(String, String, Int)]`. I added in how `year` can be written.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

```
year' :: [(String, String, Int)] -> [Int]
year' = map (\(_,_,i) -> i)
```

Oh, and if you find something that works, put it up on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , as you say you're new to Haskell.

Comment: I updated my question. I have a function that creates a list of Ints (year') and a function that finds the sum of a list of Ints (sum'), but I am having trouble tying it all together.

Answer (score 0):

For the "tying it all together" part, as a beginner, you can write code in the following style:

```
avgPub books = result where
    result = average yearlist
    yearlist = map year' books
```

After a while, you'll shorten this to

```
avgPub = average . map year'
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused right now so let me back up. I have a function called avgPub which takes a list of 2 Strings and an Int. The user can type in the command line multiple sets of books (e.g. avgPub [("publisher", "book", 1920), ("publisher1", "book1", 1989), ("publisher2", "book2", 1920)...]). I understand how to extract the years and place them into a list, as shown by my " year' " function. I know how to find the average of a list, as shown by my average' function. That being said, I still don't understand how to apply what you suggested into the information that I have.

Comment: According to what you are saying, I'm getting this (link to JPG screenshot): http://puu.sh/eoiL7/8e03d849df.png , but I can't figure out how to get it to work. I'm getting these errors: http://puu.sh/eoiZr/ffacf90de6.png

Comment: This is because your year' function should be (String,String,Int) -> Int. Adapt the type and remove the map from it. (I know you followed the advice of someone, but honestly, think about how you would extract the year from a single book that is not in a list?)